# Hide bootstrap datepicker in SharePoint

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to hide bootstrap `datepicker` on mouse wheel scroll.
In sharepoint application page I use bootstrap datepicker. now when i open datepicker and scroll the page datepicker move with the page. I found no solution for that. Can anybody help me solving that that the position of datepicker should remain same while mouse wheel scrolling.
Here is my code.

```
$(function () {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
                }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
                $('#btnPicker').click(function () {
                    $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
                });
                $('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                    $(this).datepicker('hide');
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the below code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
       $('#datepicker').datepicker('hide');
});
```

Comment: No errors. It just moves with scroll. Can't stand steady.

Comment: same position. can't stay steady.